# What is the equivalence of VB 6 controls to winapi

Tags: winapi, vb6

So far am able to create the following controls on winapi c++: Button, Checkbox, Groupbox, Listbox,Edit Text,Label,Status Bar,Shapes, Lines

However having come from VB 6 which we did in College I am having a problem creating controls like: Picture Box, Image box, which i used extensively in vb 6 to arrange other controls. In a picture box you could actually stick it to the top, left or bottom then drop controls on it. Afterwards i leave some space where mdi windows can show when opened.

Comment: Picture box, Image box, etc are made by VB6 and does not exist in base Windows API

Comment: Why would you downvote my question yet I just need ideas. You just unfair to me

Comment: For basic display of an image you can use a static control with the `SS_BITMAP` or `SS_ICON` styles. But you can't use it to "arrange other controls" like you are used from VB6. The WinAPI doesn't provide layout management for controls. That is something you'd need to write code for or use a third-party library.

Comment: Hwy Jack, I agree that the downvoters are unreasonably harsh. You ask a reasonable question for anyone coming to C++ from a more advanced tool like VB6. You explained what you needed at an appropriate level IMHO. Ignore the haters who forgot what it's like to be curious and open minded.

Comment: [Windows API index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx) -> pay attention to the *User Interface elements* section, it contains all the available controls. If I were you, I would stay away from WinAPI GUI programming. If you really need GUI, try to learn C# and WPF. WinAPI knowledge is great for backend programming in my humble opinion.

Comment: In this project the author has written a new VB6 shell around the Win32 API in order to recreate many of the default controls: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?698563-CommonControls-(Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `PictureBox` equivalent in WinAPI. Things are more involved than that. You need to load the picture yourself using the [LoadImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx) function, create a memory device context using a [CreateCompatibleDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183489(v=vs.85).aspx) function and [BitBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx) it where appropriate. Do the painting inside the [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx) message handling block.

Comment: Actually am interested in defining a docking window and not a picture because the picture box on VB 6 is a great tool to play with.